Issues trying flutter run
I'm a noob with this, so thanks in advance if you answer.
I'm trying to run a project, just to emulate it, but it's been impossible
This is the first issue that I have
[{
    "resource": "/C:/src/flutter/appstic/stickerbakeai-main-app/StickerBakeAI/android/",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#5",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The supplied phased action failed with an exception.\r\nCould not create task ':generateLockfiles'.\r\nProcess 'command 'C:\\src\\flutter\\appstic\\stickerbakeai-main-app\\StickerBakeAI\\android/gradlew.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]

Not sure if this related with flutter run issue.  But even ignoring this, I run it and I got this
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the chat were released at different times.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':package_info_plus:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

Don't understand where is the issue
My local properties seems to be ok
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\src\\flutter
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
flutter.buildMode=debug

Also compileSdkVersion 34 as you in the image
enter image description here
I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows.
Can somebody please help?
Tried to downgrade the compileSdkVersion to 30
Updated dependencies
cleaned cache
Move it to same path as Flutter path
I thought that with compile version 30 was enough but
The warnings I was getting indicated that the following plugins require Android SDK version 33 or higher:
flutter_secure_storage
google_mobile_ads
in_app_review
And the following plugins require Android SDK version 34 or higher:
package_info_plus
path_provider_android
share_plus
shared_preferences_android
sqflite
url_launcher_android
webview_flutter_android
So here I'm really confuse and complete stuck
oh! And here is the flutter doctor results
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4412], locale es-ES)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.10.0 Preview 7.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!


follow step below will help you

flutter pub cache repair

flutter clean
-flutter pub get

restart invalide cache androd studio

delete build folder

./gradlew clean in android folder
./gradlew clean assembleDebug



Thank you for your answer, please check my next post, many thanks for your help

These 3 options fixed it :

flutter pub cache repair

flutter clean pub get

restart invalide cache androd studio


Probably the 2 first commands will fix it if the project was created in Vscode
